# References explaining the term "fire in the belly"?

Tags: word-choice

What is etymology of the phrase "fire in the belly"? What is known about what it refers to?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid that questions about the etymologies of words belong on English.SE, not here. I'm going to flag this for migration.

Comment: I agree with comment above. I'm going to flag for migration.

Answer (score 1):

The origin is unknown. Check this: https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/19/messages/910.html